# Constraints between stackview and view failed

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit

This is the renderer:

[image]

But I expect this one:

[image]

The definition view:

[image]

The stackview constraints:

[image]

The Score view constraints:

[image]

Why the Score view doesn't appears? This view must be priority to keep it width size versus stackview width.

Thank you very much guys!

Comment: Remove trailing space

Answer (score 0):

Please remove trailing space to superview from ‘UIStackView’ .. ‘UIStackView’ should just have trailing with score view and score should have trailing with superview .. and set content hugging priority and compression resistance